# Javascript eval when evaluating mathematical expressions gives wrong output if number used starts with a 0

Tags: javascript, eval

So when I use:

```
eval('03*3');
```

I get 9 as I should. But when I use:

```
eval('033*3');
```

I get 81 instead of 99. I'm sure there is a good explanation for this outcome but I'm not able to find the answer. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Why would you use eval for that?

Comment: @JoeSimmons I was evaluating a javascript calculator and I noticed this behavior so I looked at the code and the code has a compute function which basically runs an eval on the form field...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In JavaScript, as in C and C++, numeric constants starting with zero are interpreted as being base-8 (octal) values. Thus `033` is decimal 27 (3 * 8 + 3). Your first example works because `03` (octal 3) is the same as decimal 3, because 3 is 3.  Multi-digit values are going to be off.

Comment: That said, this behaviour is not defined in any stanard. It's just the browsers that, for some reason, support it. This is why you should always pass the `10` parameter to `parseInt`, for example.

Comment: @Kolink: It's explained right here: http://es5.github.io/#B.1.1 (An `OctalIntegerLiteral` starts with `0` then is followed by an `OctalDigit` (`0`-`7`)).

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, in the "Compatibility" section. Because browsers already implemented it.

Comment: @Kolink: Hmm... Didn't notice the paragraph right above that.  Interesting.

Comment: @Kolink the 1st edition spec has an *OctalIntegerLiteral* token. (I guess you're still right, since it's not a standard now :)

Comment: @Pointy 2nd ed has it too. It was moved to the compatibility annex on version 3.

Comment: @Pointy Is there any way to force eval to use base-10 to evaluate the expression? I'm guessing no, but it's worth a shot asking...

Comment: @Marko: You could convert it to a string, then `parseInt` it.  `parseInt('033', 10)` is `33`.

Comment: To force base-10 on an entire string, you can use this regex: 
`toCalc = toCalc.replace(/[\d.]+/g, function(n){
    return parseFloat(n);
});`